# Android Studio add a Database

Tags: java, android, sql, database, android-room

I have a Database as an sql File and I don't know how to add it to android Studio local, I mean with ROOM. All the Tutorials I watched didn't show how to make it in JAVA. I want to have the Database local on the phone when you install the app. And the Database is already existing and a .sql file, because I didn't establish to convert it to a .db file

Thanks for your help.

I tried everything :(

Answer (score 0):

First things to do is create the `@Entity` annotated classes according to the schema of the database. That is, each `@Entity` reflects a table.

When you have these classes then create the `@Database` annotated class with all of the `@Entity` annotated classes in the list of entities of the entities parameter of the `@Database` annotation. You then compile (successfully) and the java(generated) will have a class named the same as the @Database annotated class BUT suffixed with `_Impl`. Within this class there will be a method called `createAllTables`. This will contain the **EXACT** SQL for the creation of the tables. **It is important that the database schema matches this SQL** (otherwise you will get an exception saying that the schema's do not match with the message detailing what Room expected and what was actually found).

If there are differences then you need to convert the database accordingly (it is suggested that you use the generated SQL to create new tables, load the new tables with the data from the original tables, then rename (or if confident drop them) original tables and then rename the new tables to the original names). You will then have a database with the schema according to Room's expectations.

You can then create an assets folder/directory in the project and copy the database into that folder and then add the `createFromAsset` method to the @Database. Room will copy the database from the assets folder via this method.

However, before running you would probably want to create some `@Dao` annotated interfaces (or abstract classes which have the advantage of allowing methods with bodies which can be useful) with methods appropriate for your project.

You may find this helpful:-

- [Move data from sqlite database file to room](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70580333/move-data-from-sqlite-database-file-to-room/70584194#70584194)

---

You say

> .sql file, because I didn't establish to convert it to a .db file

The extension doesn't matter (as long as it's a valid file name) and the full file name is specified as the parameter passed to the `createFromAsset` method.

---

**Working Example**

---

**The existing database**

For this example the existing database consists of 3 tables:-

- the **user** table with 3 columns:-

  - **userid** (INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL) i.e. unique identifier
  - **username** a textual type **BUT** defined using a type as ***NOTAROOMKNOWNTYPE*** (a type as it says that Room will not allow)
  - **useremail** with a type of TEXT
- the **meeting** table with 4 columns:-

  - **meetingid** (again INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL)
  - **meetingname** with a type of TEXT
  - **startdatetime** with a type of integer (intended for a time stamp)
  - **enddatetime** with a type of integer (again timestamp)
- the **usermeetingmap** table with 2 columns to enable a many-many relationship between user and meeting (a user can attend many meetings and a meeting can have many users)

  - **usermap** with a type of LONG (not supported/known by room)
  - **meetingmap** likewise.

The following is the SQL used to create the tables, populate them with some data and also to extract the data:-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS usermeetingmap;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS meeting;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (
  userid INTEGER,
  username NOTAROOMKNOWNTYPE,
  useremail TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY (userid)
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS meeting (
  meetingid INTEGER,
  meetingname TEXT,
  startdatetime integer,
  enddatetime integer,
  PRIMARY KEY (meetingid)
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS usermeetingmap (
  usermap LONG NOT NULL,
  meetingmap LONG NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (usermap, meetingmap),
  FOREIGN KEY (usermap) REFERENCES user (userid) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (meetingmap) REFERENCES meeting (meetingid) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

DELETE FROM usermeetingmap;
DELETE FROM user;
DELETE FROM meeting;
INSERT INTO user VALUES 
    (1,'User1','user1@mail.com'),
    (2,'User2','user2@hotmail.com'),
    (3,'User3','user3@gmail.com'),
    (4,'User4','user4@yandex.com')
;
INSERT  OR IGNORE INTO meeting VALUES
    (100,'Meeting1',strftime('%s','now','-7 days'),strftime('%s','now','-7 days','+3 hours')),
    (200,'Meeting2',strftime('%s','now','-6 days','+1 hour'),strftime('%s','now','-6 day','+4 hours')),
    (300,'Meeting3',strftime('%s','now','-5 days','+2 hour'),strftime('%s','now','-5 day','+5 hours')),
    (400,'Meeting3',strftime('%s','now','-4 days','+3 hour'),strftime('%s','now','-4 day','+6 hours'))
;
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO usermeetingmap VALUES
    (1,100),(3,100),
    (2,200),(4,200),
    (1,300),(2,300),(3,300),(4,300)
;

SELECT 
    user.username,user.useremail, 
    meeting.meetingname, 
    datetime(meeting.startdatetime,'unixepoch') AS starts,
    datetime(meeting.enddatetime,'unixepoch') AS ends FROM user 
    JOIN usermeetingmap ON user.userid = usermeetingmap.usermap
    JOIN meeting ON usermeetingmap.meetingmap = meeting.meetingid
ORDER BY meetingid
;
```

The result of the query:-

[image]

**Step 1 - Create the `@Entity` annotated classes**

- **Note** I suggest writing 1 @Entity annotated class at a time, then compiling (CTRL + F9) to see if there are an reported issues.

  - You could also inspect the generated java and make notes of any discrepancies between the existing database and the room database.

**Step 1.1 Create the User class**

From the above we know that the User table should have 3 columns, the primary key being the **userid** column. **Room** requires that all tables have a primary key (it does not support WITHOUT ROWID tables).

So the **User** class could be:-

```
@Entity
class User {
    @PrimaryKey
    Long userid=null;
    String username; /* NOTE CANNOT USE NOTAROOMKNOWNTYPE as we know it's a TEXT type then java String type */
    String useremail;
}
```

To test this the **`@Database`** annotated class will now be added to suit this single table e.g.:-

```
@Database( entities = {User.class}, exportSchema = false, version = 1)
abstract class TheDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
}
```

If the project is compiled (successfully i.e. it is suggested that you ALWAYS check the build log) then you can compare the SQL of the User table that Room expects e.g. :-

[image]

In this case we compare the two (Room SQL with Original SQL/schema):-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `User` (`userid` INTEGER, `username` TEXT, `useremail` TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(`userid`))
```

and
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (userid INTEGER,username NOTAROOMKNOWNTYPE,useremail TEXT,PRIMARY KEY (userid));

- They differ

  - the **username** column has TEXT v NOTAROOMKNOWNTYPE. **THIS MUST BE CHANGED TO SUIT ROOM**
  - note that Room encloses all table/column names in `'s that just ensures that the names are taken as names.

**Step 1.2 Meeting class** first attempt:-

```
@Entity
class Meeting {
    @PrimaryKey
    Long meetingid=null;
    String meetingname;
    long startdatetime;
    long enddatetime;
}
```

Then amend the **TheDatabase** to include the new entity:-

```
@Database( entities = {User.class,Meeting.class}, exportSchema = false, version = 1)
```

Again compare SQL (Room v original):-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Meeting` (`meetingid` INTEGER, `meetingname` TEXT, `startdatetime` INTEGER NOT NULL, `enddatetime` INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(`meetingid`))

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS meeting (meetingid INTEGER,meetingname TEXT,startdatetime integer,enddatetime integer,PRIMARY KEY (meetingid));
```

- **There is a difference** Room has added the NOT NULL constraint for the startdatetime and enddatetime columns. Room would not accept this. So something has to be changed.

  - for primitives (long in this case) Room will always add a NOT NULL constraint. A way around this is to instead use an Object. In this case Long instead of Long.

So the **Meeting** class can be changed to :-

```
@Entity
class Meeting {
    @PrimaryKey
    Long meetingid=null;
    String meetingname;
    Long startdatetime;
    Long enddatedate;
}
```

And after Compiling then Room's generated SQL is now:-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Meeting` (`meetingid` INTEGER, `meetingname` TEXT, `startdatetime` INTEGER, `enddatetime` INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY(`meetingid`))
```

**Step 1.3 UserMeetingMap class**

```
@Entity(
        /* @Primary can only be used to annotated a single member/column as a composite primary key is required then */
        primaryKeys = {"usermap","meetingmap"},
        /* As Foreign Key constraints have been used then */
        foreignKeys = {
                @ForeignKey(
                        entity = User.class,
                        parentColumns = {"userid"},
                        childColumns = {"usermap"},
                        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
                        onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
                ),
                @ForeignKey(
                        entity = Meeting.class,
                        parentColumns = {"meetingid"},
                        childColumns = {"meetingmap"},
                        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
                        onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
                )
        }
)
class UserMeetingMap {
    long usermap;
    long meetingmap;
}
```

the `@Database` annotation is changed to:-

```
@Database( entities = {User.class,Meeting.class,UserMeetingMap.class}, exportSchema = false, version = 1)
```

After compiling then the Room v Original SQL is:-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `UserMeetingMap` (`usermap` INTEGER NOT NULL, `meetingmap` INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(`usermap`, `meetingmap`), FOREIGN KEY(`usermap`) REFERENCES `User`(`userid`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE , FOREIGN KEY(`meetingmap`) REFERENCES `Meeting`(`meetingid`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE )

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS usermeetingmap (usermap LONG NOT NULL,meetingmap LONG NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (usermap, meetingmap),FOREIGN KEY (usermap) REFERENCES user (userid) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,FOREIGN KEY (meetingmap) REFERENCES meeting (meetingid) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

As can be seen the original has type LONG rather than INTEGER, **THIS MUST BE CHANGED**.

**STEP 2 Converting the original database**

Using the approach we can see that unless the database is converted that Room will reject the database as not being the expected database. As such, due to Room's requirements the original database **MUST BE ALTERED ACCORDINGLY**.

In summary the unacceptable ***NOTAROOMKNOWNTYPE*** must be changed to **TEXT** and the two occurrences of ***LONG*** must be changed to **INTEGER**.

The easiest way is to use an SQLite tool and:-

1. Rename the original tables
2. Create the new tables by copying the generated SQL (i.e. Room's expected tables)
3. Per table, use INSERT INTO table SELECT * FROM original_table;

   1. Note that if using Foreign Keys (and not deferring or turning off foreign key support) then parent tables must be loaded before children.
4. Drop the original tables
5. Optionally, but suggested, VACUUM
6. Save the database

e.g. for this demo the following was used:-

```
/* Just in case */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS original_usermeetingmap;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS original_user;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS original_meeting;
ALTER TABLE user RENAME TO original_user;
ALTER TABLE meeting RENAME TO original_meeting;
ALTER TABLE usermeetingmap RENAME TO original_usermeetingmap;

/* COPY ROOM GENERATE SQL HERE */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `User` (`userid` INTEGER, `username` TEXT, `useremail` TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(`userid`));
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Meeting` (`meetingid` INTEGER, `meetingname` TEXT, `startdatetime` INTEGER, `enddatetime` INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY(`meetingid`));
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `UserMeetingMap` (`usermap` INTEGER NOT NULL, `meetingmap` INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(`usermap`, `meetingmap`), FOREIGN KEY(`usermap`) REFERENCES `User`(`userid`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE , FOREIGN KEY(`meetingmap`) REFERENCES `Meeting`(`meetingid`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE );
/* COPY THE DATA */
INSERT INTO user SELECT * FROM original_user;
INSERT INTO meeting SELECT * FROM original_meeting;
INSERT INTO usermeetingmap SELECT * FROM original_usermeetingmap;
/* JUST CHECKING */
SELECT 
    user.username,user.useremail, 
    meeting.meetingname, 
    datetime(meeting.startdatetime,'unixepoch') AS starts,
    datetime(meeting.enddatetime,'unixepoch') AS ends FROM user 
    JOIN usermeetingmap ON user.userid = usermeetingmap.usermap
    JOIN meeting ON usermeetingmap.meetingmap = meeting.meetingid
ORDER BY meetingid
;
/* ONCE TESTED AS 100% OK uncomment following */
/*DROP TABLE IF EXISTS original_usermeetingmap;*/
/*DROP TABLE IF EXISTS original_user;*/
/*DROP TABLE IF EXISTS original_meeting;*/
/*VACUUM; to tidy up storage/free space */
```

**STEP 3 Preparing the Converted database**

Create the assets folder.

[image]

Copy the saved database, renaming if/as you want, into the assets folder (example where it has been renamed to the stupid file name `anything.anything`).

Amend the **TheDatabase** class (as one way) to provide a built (Rooms terminology) adatabase using the `createFromAsset` method e.g.

```
@Database( entities = {User.class,Meeting.class,UserMeetingMap.class}, exportSchema = false, version = 1)
abstract class TheDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    private static volatile TheDatabase INSTANCE;

    public static TheDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE==null) {
            INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase.class,"the_database_.xyz")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries() /* for brevity of demo */
                    .createFromAsset("anything.anything")
                    .build();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

- **NOTE** the parameter for the `createFromAsset` method. It MUST match the file name of the asset (and any sub-directories if placed in a sub-directory of the assets folder).

Here's the Android View showing the asset:-

[image]

Note that just getting an Instance of the TheDatabase **DOES NOT OPEN THE DATABASE** you have to access.

As the final proof of the above working then the following activity code:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TheDatabase dbInstance;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        dbInstance = TheDatabase.getInstance(this); /* DATABASE WILL NOT BE COPIED/OPENED MUST ACCESS IT */
        /* Access the database by getting the schema and dumping the cursor */
        Cursor csr = dbInstance.getOpenHelper().getReadableDatabase().query("SELECT * FROM sqlite_master");
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr);
    }
}
```

**Result** (as per the log)

```
2022-11-18 12:30:53.220 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@17eeb83
2022-11-18 12:30:53.220 I/System.out: 0 {
2022-11-18 12:30:53.220 I/System.out:    type=table
2022-11-18 12:30:53.220 I/System.out:    name=original_user
2022-11-18 12:30:53.220 I/System.out:    tbl_name=original_user
2022-11-18 12:30:53.220 I/System.out:    rootpage=2
2022-11-18 12:30:53.220 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE "original_user" (`userid` INTEGER, `username` TEXT, `useremail` TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(`userid`))
2022-11-18 12:30:53.220 I/System.out: }
2022-11-18 12:30:53.220 I/System.out: 1 {
2022-11-18 12:30:53.220 I/System.out:    type=table
2022-11-18 12:30:53.220 I/System.out:    name=original_meeting
2022-11-18 12:30:53.220 I/System.out:    tbl_name=original_meeting
2022-11-18 12:30:53.220 I/System.out:    rootpage=3
2022-11-18 12:30:53.221 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE "original_meeting" (`meetingid` INTEGER, `meetingname` TEXT, `startdatetime` INTEGER, `enddatetime` INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY(`meetingid`))
2022-11-18 12:30:53.221 I/System.out: }
2022-11-18 12:30:53.221 I/System.out: 2 {
2022-11-18 12:30:53.221 I/System.out:    type=table
2022-11-18 12:30:53.221 I/System.out:    name=original_usermeetingmap
2022-11-18 12:30:53.221 I/System.out:    tbl_name=original_usermeetingmap
2022-11-18 12:30:53.221 I/System.out:    rootpage=4
2022-11-18 12:30:53.221 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE "original_usermeetingmap" (`usermap` INTEGER NOT NULL, `meetingmap` INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(`usermap`, `meetingmap`), FOREIGN KEY(`usermap`) REFERENCES "original_user"(`userid`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE , FOREIGN KEY(`meetingmap`) REFERENCES "original_meeting"(`meetingid`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE )
2022-11-18 12:30:53.221 I/System.out: }
2022-11-18 12:30:53.221 I/System.out: 3 {
2022-11-18 12:30:53.221 I/System.out:    type=index
2022-11-18 12:30:53.221 I/System.out:    name=sqlite_autoindex_original_usermeetingmap_1
2022-11-18 12:30:53.221 I/System.out:    tbl_name=original_usermeetingmap
2022-11-18 12:30:53.221 I/System.out:    rootpage=5
2022-11-18 12:30:53.221 I/System.out:    sql=null
2022-11-18 12:30:53.221 I/System.out: }
2022-11-18 12:30:53.221 I/System.out: 4 {
2022-11-18 12:30:53.221 I/System.out:    type=table
2022-11-18 12:30:53.221 I/System.out:    name=User
2022-11-18 12:30:53.221 I/System.out:    tbl_name=User
2022-11-18 12:30:53.221 I/System.out:    rootpage=6
2022-11-18 12:30:53.221 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE `User` (`userid` INTEGER, `username` TEXT, `useremail` TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(`userid`))
2022-11-18 12:30:53.221 I/System.out: }
2022-11-18 12:30:53.221 I/System.out: 5 {
2022-11-18 12:30:53.221 I/System.out:    type=table
2022-11-18 12:30:53.222 I/System.out:    name=Meeting
2022-11-18 12:30:53.222 I/System.out:    tbl_name=Meeting
2022-11-18 12:30:53.222 I/System.out:    rootpage=7
2022-11-18 12:30:53.222 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE `Meeting` (`meetingid` INTEGER, `meetingname` TEXT, `startdatetime` INTEGER, `enddatetime` INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY(`meetingid`))
2022-11-18 12:30:53.222 I/System.out: }
2022-11-18 12:30:53.222 I/System.out: 6 {
2022-11-18 12:30:53.222 I/System.out:    type=table
2022-11-18 12:30:53.222 I/System.out:    name=UserMeetingMap
2022-11-18 12:30:53.222 I/System.out:    tbl_name=UserMeetingMap
2022-11-18 12:30:53.222 I/System.out:    rootpage=8
2022-11-18 12:30:53.222 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE `UserMeetingMap` (`usermap` INTEGER NOT NULL, `meetingmap` INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(`usermap`, `meetingmap`), FOREIGN KEY(`usermap`) REFERENCES `User`(`userid`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE , FOREIGN KEY(`meetingmap`) REFERENCES `Meeting`(`meetingid`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE )
2022-11-18 12:30:53.222 I/System.out: }
2022-11-18 12:30:53.222 I/System.out: 7 {
2022-11-18 12:30:53.222 I/System.out:    type=index
2022-11-18 12:30:53.222 I/System.out:    name=sqlite_autoindex_UserMeetingMap_1
2022-11-18 12:30:53.223 I/System.out:    tbl_name=UserMeetingMap
2022-11-18 12:30:53.224 I/System.out:    rootpage=9
2022-11-18 12:30:53.224 I/System.out:    sql=null
2022-11-18 12:30:53.224 I/System.out: }
2022-11-18 12:30:53.224 I/System.out: 8 {
2022-11-18 12:30:53.224 I/System.out:    type=table
2022-11-18 12:30:53.224 I/System.out:    name=android_metadata
2022-11-18 12:30:53.224 I/System.out:    tbl_name=android_metadata
2022-11-18 12:30:53.224 I/System.out:    rootpage=10
2022-11-18 12:30:53.224 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT)
2022-11-18 12:30:53.224 I/System.out: }
2022-11-18 12:30:53.224 I/System.out: 9 {
2022-11-18 12:30:53.224 I/System.out:    type=table
2022-11-18 12:30:53.224 I/System.out:    name=room_master_table
2022-11-18 12:30:53.224 I/System.out:    tbl_name=room_master_table
2022-11-18 12:30:53.224 I/System.out:    rootpage=11
2022-11-18 12:30:53.225 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE room_master_table (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,identity_hash TEXT)
2022-11-18 12:30:53.225 I/System.out: }
2022-11-18 12:30:53.225 I/System.out: <<<<<
```

- **Note that the original tables have not been dropped** *(wasting space is not an issue for this demo)*

As a final proof the query used when creating the demo database can be used with Android Studio's App Inspection and:-

[image]